# Teria como melhorar o desempenho desse código?

Tags: c

Já achei a resolução dessa questão e todos os resultados estão de acordo com o que a questão pede,porém acho que a solução ela está um pouco lenta, por que ela está dando Time limit exceeded

[Link da questão](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2478)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 struct p
 {
    char presente[3][100], nome[100];
 };

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
   int  i, j;
   int teste;
   char nome1[100], nome2[100];
   while(scanf("%d", &teste) != EOF)
   {
     struct p presentes[teste];

      for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
      {
         scanf("%s", presentes[i].nome);
         for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         {
            scanf("%s", presentes[i].presente[j]);
         }
      }
      int achou = 0, c = 0;
      do
      {
         scanf("%s %s", nome1, nome2);
         for(i = 0, achou = 0; i < teste; i++)
         {
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if(0 == strcmp(presentes[i].nome, nome1) && (0 == strcmp(presentes[i].presente[j], nome2)))
                {
                    achou = 1;
                    c++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(achou == 1)
        {
            printf("Uhul! Seu amigo secreto vai adorar o/\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Tente Novamente!\n");
        }
    }
    while(c != 3);
}
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que pode fazer para melhorar o desempenho do código é colocar um  `break;` em cada `for` quando já achou, da forma como eu respondi na sua ultima pergunta. Se não resolver tem de optar por outro algoritmo/solução

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro, Por gentileza coloque o problema também pra nos avaliar, eu suponho que esse problema seja alguém do URI certo?
Mas olhando seu código parece poderia ser melhorado em alguns aspectos

```
for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if(0 == strcmp(presentes[i].nome, nome1) && (0 == strcmp(presentes[i].presente[j], nome2)))
            {
                achou = 1;
                c++;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Usando o break você para a execução quando acha a tal situação.

Comment: Olha o link da questão eu coloquei na descrição do problema, fiz o que você fez coloquei o break, porém continua dando ime limit exceeded.

Comment: tente diminuir o tamanho do vetor de caracteres, 100 pode esta comendo muita memoria desnecessaria

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, posto a minha solução aqui?

Comment: Sim, por favor!